# CustomValidator fires when click on button

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have the following code:

```
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="validateOnFinalSubmit"
    ErrorMessage="none"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

I like the Custom Validator to fire when the user clicks on the button called btnSubmit. How can I modify the above code for it to do so

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
```

One way I see that it can be done is to add ValidationGroup to both the button and the Validator. Is this the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MSDN's page for [ClientValidationFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomValidator.ClientValidationFunction(v=VS.110).aspx) as well as their [walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z2h4sw(v=vs.80).aspx) with a section for CustomValidators. From the walkthrough:

> You will add two blocks of custom validation code. The first is the
>   custom validation code that runs when the page is submitted. You must
>   always have server-side validation logic for a CustomValidator
>   control. You will also write some client script (ECMAScript or
>   JavaScript) that performs a similar check in the browser, so that the
>   user can have immediate feedback.